# jQuery UI draggable doesn't work on created element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Draggable function works on other already created elements, but not on the one i'm creating within a function after submit button.
I've checked if i'm adding an id to 'li' elements and it works, so why can't I drag it?
It works when I use it on whole 'ul' element.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="entry">
    <button id="entryButton">button</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>





$("#entryButton").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault(); //stops refreshing
        var query = $("#entry").val();
        if (query !== "") {
            var registry = "<div id='drag'>" + query + "</div>"
            $("#list").append(registry)
            $("#entry").val("");
            return false; //also stops refreshing
            console.log(registry);
                           }
         })

    $("#drag").draggable({
      axis: "y"
      });
```

Comment: You should use draggable function after create the element

Comment: If I put it inside function, only the first created element is draggable

Comment: Hence you should use twice jhst copy it

Comment: I have tried evey possibility and it's still only one first created element that is draggable

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake on my answer. I have updated it and now it will properly apply the draggable to all the newly added elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only use an id once, so I would suggest that you use class for that. Furthermore, you should add the draggable to the element after creation, as Ferhat BAŞ has said.

https://jsfiddle.net/exqn1aoc/2/

```
$("#entryButton").click(function(){
    event.preventDefault(); //stops refreshing
    var query = $("#entry").val();
    if (query !== "") {
        var registry = "<div class='drag'>" + query + "</div>"

        $("#list").append(registry);
        $('#list').children().last().draggable();
        $("#entry").val("");
        return false; //also stops refreshing
        console.log(registry);
                       }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use class instead of id for multi pal created item to drag and put your  draggable inside button click.

```js
$("#entryButton").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault(); //stops refreshing
  var query = $("#entry").val();
  if (query !== "") {
    var registry = "<div id='drag' class='drag'>" + query + "</div>"
    $("#list").append(registry)
    $("#entry").val("");
     $(".drag").draggable({
      axis: "y"
    });
    return false; //also stops refreshing
    console.log(registry);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="entry">
    <button id="entryButton">button</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to put the draggable() function inside your click function.

Second, do not use `id` . Duplicate `id's` are not valid HTML and that's what causing only the first `#drag` to be draggable. Use class instead

See snippet below

```js
$("#entryButton").click(function() {
  event.preventDefault(); //stops refreshing
  var query = $("#entry").val();
  if (query !== "") {
    var registry = "<div class='drag'>" + query + "</div>"
    $("#list").append(registry)
    $("#entry").val("");
    $(".drag").draggable()
    return false; //also stops refreshing
    console.log(registry);

  }
})
```

```css
.drag {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="entry">
    <button id="entryButton">button</button>
  </form>
  <ul id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```